# Unable to get a facebook page's feed onto my app

Tags: android, facebook

I want my app to just display the posts published by a facebook page without any authentication. Here is the code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
    String APP_ID = "1234567890";         
    String APP_SECRET = "1a2b3c4defghijk";
    String OWNER_OF_FEED = "somepage";

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(
            "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="+ 
            APP_ID + 
            "&client_secret="+APP_SECRET+"&grant_type=client_credentials");

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    String access_token = client.execute(get, responseHandler);

    String uri = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + OWNER_OF_FEED + "/feed?"
            + access_token;

    get = new HttpGet(uri);
    String responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);

    // responseBody contains JSON-encoded feed

    //textview.setText(responseBody);
    TextView txtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feed);
    txtv.setText(String.valueOf(responseBody)); 
    }

    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

But am unable to get any content on the app. 
I have included the permission for internet access in the manifest file.

New code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=289781571139242");

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = isw.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                data = isw.read();
                System.out.print(current);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is actually a way to get a page public feed without user permission!

**Solution**

1. Get the page Facebook Profile Id: the simplest way is to query the Graph API http://graph.facebook.com/{YourPageUsername} . *e.g. for oStream Android App https://graph.facebook.com/oStreamApp will return Facebook Profile Id 289781571139242*
2. Request the RSS of the Facebook page feed:
   Make an http request to https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id={yourAppId} *e.g. For oStream Android App the Public https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=289781571139242*

An **Android implementation** will simply be:

1. Make an http request to http://graph.facebook.com/{YourPageUsername}
2. Parse the content and get the YourPageId
3. Make an http request to https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id={yourAppId}
4. Parse the content
5. Display the content as you wish

**Side note**
This question is not very much about Android but just with Facebook API.

Comment: May I ask you to comment the question or make any other think to notify @K_K?

Comment: Hey! thanks a lot :) I'll give your solution a try ASAP. 
I had given up because everyone was like it's not possible.

Comment: @StefanoPochet I made the changes according to your answer. Unfortunately, I still get a blank page! A little more help?!

Comment: when i put graph link in browser it works well but when i get it in android app return error .. what the wrong ?

Comment: how to load more feed?

Answer (score 5):

I've done it with the access token.
There's a tool in facebook developpers "Tool/Access Token Tool"
You'll get an access token called "app token" that you can use like this :
https://graph.facebook.com/*"Your Facebook ID"*/feed?access_token=*"Your app token"*;

Then you'll get the json object of your feed  and you'll be able to do whatever you want using JSON parsing methods.

Your app token will not move until somebody change the password or try to get another "app secret id" in your app management page on Facebook.
Enjoy!