# Loading/displaying public facebook-page data into own webpage

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to load some posts asynchronously via the javascript SDK from facebook. I'm loading the javascript files at the bottom of the page:

```
<html>
<head>.....</head>
<body>
 .....
 .....
 .....
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/res/jquery.stp.js"  charset="utf-8"></script>
</body></html>
```

In jquery.stp.js I'm loading these things in this order: 
- the javascript sdk
- some jquery-things
- a function loadFBPosts()
- fb.init()

The file:

```
var isLoaded = false;   
(function(d, debug){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document, /*debug*/ false));

$(function(){
    //some jquery event things
})

function loadFBPosts(fbPageId) {
        // Facebook call
        if(isLoaded) {      
                //do some things with the FB.api()
                //and catch errors...
            }else{
                //api not loaded...
            }
 }

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'xxxxx', 
          channelUrl : '//lab.example.com/channel.php', 
          status     : true, 
          cookie     : true, 
          xfbml      : true  
        });

                isLoaded = true;
        laadFBPosts();  // here after FB.init is initialized call the function.
};
```

**Questions**

Now something odd happens. If I run this page an error pops up: "An access token is required to request this resource" with error-code 104.
But if I click a link on the page `<a href='javascript:loadFBPosts()'>click</a>` then the function gets execute like it should.

How is this possible? The resources I try to get with the FB.api() are from public facebook pages. eg FB.api('/218818688131271/posts?limit=5') so I shouldn't need an access token. Right?

If I do need an acces token: how do I obtain one if I don't want to bother every visitor with a login screen; because it's just a displaying of public info....

The only thing I want to do is to display the last 5 posts off my page and the upcoming events.

Comment: Easiest way to retrieve page posts is RSS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15248957/1515819

Comment: That's a nice work-around, but: 1 - it only works for the posts. And not for instance the public events etc... 2 - the (amount of) info given is not the same as through the graph option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to get a facebook page's feed onto my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138860/unable-to-get-a-facebook-pages-feed-onto-my-app)