# why graph facebook return error in android?

Tags: android, json, graph

when i run this graph link on browser , it works fine and return valid json object but when i run it from android app it returns error .. i want to know why that ?? i heard about something called access token .. how can i use it if it is neccessary ??

**on browser**

```
{
   "about": "\u0627\u0644\u0635\u0641\u062d\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0631\u0633\u0645\u064a\u0629 \u0644\u0640\"\u0634\u0628\u0643\u0629 \u0631\u0635\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0625\u062e\u0628\u0627\u0631\u064a\u0629\" \u060c \u0625\u0639\u0644\u0627\u0645 \u064a\u0635\u0646\u0639\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u062c\u0645\u0647\u0648\u0631 \nwww.rassd.com ",
   "birthday": "01/25/2011",
   "category": "Media/news/publishing",
   "description": "\u0631\u0627\u0642\u0628 .. \u0648\u0635\u0648\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u062d\u062f\u0627\u062b \u0648\u0627\u0631\u0633\u0644\u0647\u0627 \u0644\u0646\u0627 \u0645\u0628\u0627\u0634\u0631\u0629 \u0648\u0641\u064a \u0623\u0633\u0631\u0639 \u0648\u0642\u0640\u062a \u0639\u0628\u0631 \u0631\u0633\u0627\u0626\u0644 \u0635\u0641\u062d\u0629 \u0631\u0635\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0631\u0633\u0645\u064a\u0629 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0641\u064a\u0633 \u0628\u0648\u0643: www.fb.com/RNN.news",
   "is_published": true,
   "location": {
      "street": "",
      "city": "Cairo",
      "state": "",
      "country": "Egypt",
      "zip": "2512011"
   },
   "talking_about_count": 386793,
   "username": "RNN.NEWS",
   "website": "http://www.rassd.com",
   "were_here_count": 0,
   "id": "103622369714881",
   "name": "R.N.N | \u0634\u0628\u0643\u0629 \u0631\u0635\u062f",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/RNN.NEWS",
   "likes": 2890218,
   "cover": {
      "cover_id": 590822204328226,
      "source": "http://sphotos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/s720x720/1148784_590822204328226_2130683517_n.jpg",
      "offset_y": 0,
      "offset_x": 0
   }
}
```

**in android app**

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: RNN.3t554t54",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Facebook SDK?

Comment: no, i treat with at like as any json code from any site

Comment: You should use Facebook SDK 3.0+ to properly fetch the information.

Comment: sorry, i am new in android .. can you give me a link to explain that ?

Comment: Sure, but can you please tell what information are you trying to parse and what link are you using ?

Comment: i added this question about the problem .. i want to get feeds of any public page and display it .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548210/error-in-facebook-graph-org-json-jsonexception-no-value-for-name

Comment: first of all i will get its id, name and profile image

Comment: then get its feeds by its id

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following link to solve your problem.
[Unable to get a facebook page's feed onto my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138860/unable-to-get-a-facebook-pages-feed-onto-my-app?rq=1)
Thanks.

Comment: the same point in this question .. when i call graph url in my app it returns with error as shown above